# How to make emacs accept UTF-8 (uppercase) encoding?

Tags: emacs, character-encoding, standards

The following specifies file's character encoding:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

But the uppercase variant:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

produces:

> Warning (mule): Invalid coding system `UTF-8' is specified for the
>   current buffer/file by the :coding tag. It is highly recommended to
>   fix it before writing to a file.

Version: `GNU Emacs 23.3.1`

`UTF-8` is an [official name for the utf-8 character encoding](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch03.pdf#G7404).

The obvious `add-to-coding-system-list` function doesn't apply in this case. How to make UTF-8 to be alias for utf-8 in the `coding` declaration?

Comment: Since Amcs doesn't understand it, why would you want to use `-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-` rather than `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-`?

Comment: @Stefan: The question is *how* to do it. What the context when it is a sensible thing to do it is another question.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think, that following code will help you:

```
(define-coding-system-alias 'UTF-8 'utf-8)
```

Comment: I put this before these lines and it works for me on Aquamacs 24.5:

    `(set-language-environment "UTF-8")
    (set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)`